# Formula to identify a list of codes in various combinations

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

Bit of a tough one to explain, but here we go... I have a large database (15K rows) of unique codes (AA1, AA2, AB1, etc.) in letter & numbers convention that identify them to a specific name (in Finance, this is a list of ISINs to each specific security).

Visual of the Excel database:

[image: Visual of the Excel database]

A pre-defined combination of certain unique identifiers will create a "fund" (ie. AA1, AA2 and AB1 together form Fund1). Those unique identifiers can be arranged in a variety of ways to form part of multiple "funds" (ie. AA1 and AA2 together will form Fund2, AA2 and AB1 together will form Fund3, etc).

Visual of the various "Funds":

[image: Visual of the "funds" (solutions)]

[image: Visual of the various "Funds"]

I'm trying to find a way in that the formula can go through this database, identify if any combination of unique identifiers together form a "fund", and return it back. If I could somehow define the combination of unique identifiers as a single value or characteristic that could be compared against, I think this would solve the issue.

I have tried a million of ways, but nothing seems to work. Would really appreciate any help here!

Comment: It is not clear, mainly because you have not included them in your pictures, how the "unique codes" (AA1, AA2, AB1, etc) relate to the individual assets (where an asset can be identified from its ISIN). Does one "unique code" have just one asset corresponding to it or is it possible for several assets to share the same unique code?

Comment: So does the second picture (list of funds) have multiple asset id columns for each asset it owns? Or is it simply listed one after each other in a single cell space delimited?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. The unique codes I referred to (AA1, AA2, AB1, etc) are actually the ISINs, just wanted to use a more commonly known terminology rather than using the financial term. Every asset has only 1 unique code (ISIN). No asset has two different codes. 

For the second question, the "list of funds" have multiple asset ID in different rows. I have also tried transposing the database so it is separated by columns, and concatenating the text to join them by a "-" delimiter.  The problem with this approach is that the unique codes are not always sorted.

Comment: What's the result table you need? I'm not very clearly your question, the problem can be described more simply.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a zoomed out screenshot of the funds sheet. I'm guessing the thicker dark lines are "fund separators", but we cant see the fund names. What makes this trickier is that the data is listed sequentially and some funds have 2 ISINs others have five or whatever. It varies per fund

Comment: Also, when you say "identify if any combination of unique identifiers together form a "fund", do you mean any random combination/all possible combinations or rather that you specify say three assets and the formula spits out all funds that contain those three? Ps. to the reader, your two screenshots kinda look like the same thing (ie. the asset sheet and the funds sheet looks the same, except the columns are swapped)

Comment: I have added another picture showing the full list. As you correctly point out, the darker lines represent a change in the "fund" itself (which we call solutions). Solutions have around between 2-7 individual ISINs inside, so that indeed makes it trickier.

Comment: In regards to your second question, it could be any/all random combinations. More specifically, from the initial master database, I will specify sections of between 5-30 ISINs each that ideally the formula can identify a) if any solutions are inside those combinations of ISINs and b) being a) true, which solutions are these (could be a combination of solution 1, 2 and 3 for example). One tricky aspect is that the ISINs are not sorted in any obvious order, just randomly dropped. This means that any type of aggregation to identify the solutions can't depend on the order of the underlying ISINs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the funds sheet, lets say you can search a text string containing all isin's in its portfolio (portfolio string)

Specify three isin's in three cells/columns to search for and find funds owning it. Use FIND to search the portfolio string on each row of the funds sheet, looking up one search isin at a time / per column. Wrap each FIND in a ISNUMBER. The funds sheet would look like

```
Fund    portfolio string    AX1    AA2    BA3
Fund1   AX1 AA3 BA3         TRUE   FALSE  TRUE
```

Now add a fourth column that SUM the three search boolean columns. A TRUE value will sum as a 1 and FALSE as a zero. The above example will SUM to 2. Now use the built-in Excel Filter to find funds that match say 2 or 3 search ISINs.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Boolean logic is the closest I have gotten to solving the issue but doesn't quite do the trick. The database has 70+ solutions and 15,000 ISINs, so when I try to use the FIND formula it can't really compare each individual ISIN to each 70+ solutions... It does at least help me identify which portfolios have a high probability of holding a solution, but think the identifying part will have to remain manual for now.

Comment: It might be possible to do better. I've asked some more questions in the comments above.